# I can’t start screen recording Appium on Chinese devices oppo,huawei

Tags: android, mobile, appium, appium-android

I start and stop screen recording with the code below, but I get this error on Chinese phones such as oppo and huawei.

It returns this as an error. :

openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: The expected screen record file ‘/sdcard/70454702.mp4’ does not exist after 5000ms. Is screenrecord utility available and operational on the device under test?

[image]